# Filtering Datagird with 1+ comboBoxes - multiple Filterconditions (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, filter, combobox, datagrid

the scenario is easy, but I’m stuck with the details:

I have a datagrid which is bound to an observable collection in my viewModel. I want to filter my datagrid with the entries of three comboBoxes. There are other posts here on multiple filters, but I could not find one that was adequate to my case or MVVM.  During my research I came across ControlViewSource as the way to go quiet a few times. For the sake of simplicity, I included an image after the text. Here is my code: 
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <viewModels: MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key=“CVS“ Source=“{Binding FirstFilter}“/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation=“Horizontal“>
      <ComboBox x:Name=“ItemsFilter“ ItemsSource=“{Binding ItemsList}“ SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
      <ComboBox x:Name=“ElementsFilter“ ItemsSource=“{Binding ElementsList}“ SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentElement}"/>
      <ComboBox x:Name=“ValuesFilter“ ItemsSource=“{Binding ValuesList}“ SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentValue}"/>
</StackPanel>

<DataGrid x:Name=“MainGrid“ ItemsSource=“{Binding DataList}“/>
</StackPanel>
```

My aim is to filter the data in the datagrid according to the selected item in each comboBox. To give you an idea, let’s make this simple:

- comboBox „ItemsFilter“ has the entries „AllItems“, „ItemsA“, and „ItemsB (whereas A and B refers to an item category like „watermelons“ and „apples“, so that all „AllItems“ would be „AllFruits“).
- comboBox „ElementsFilter“ furthermore determines the selection of „ItemsFilter“: it should have something like „AllElements“, „ElementA“, „ElementB“ (whereas this could refer to brands, so like, „Watermelons“ (ITemsFilter) and „Brand A“ (ElementsFilter).
- comboBox „ValuesFilter“ would be „AllValues“, „ValueA“, „ValueB“, and could be prices.

So, until now, I got ONE filter to work. Code in my viewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataList {get; set;} = new     ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> FirstFilter {get; set;} = new     ObservableCollection<DataItem>();

private ICollectionView _myFilterView;
public ICollectionView MyFilterView
{
   get {return _myFilterView;}
   set 
   {
      _myFilterView = value;
      OnPropertyChange(nameof(MyFilterView);
   }
}

private string _currentItem;
public string CurrentItem
{
   get { return _currentItem}
   set 
   {
      _currentItem = value;
      OnPropertyChange(nameofMyFilterView);
   }
}
   // I also have properties CurrentElement, CurrentValue --> all of them representing the currently selected item, element or value (as string) in one of the associated comboBoxes.

public MainViewModel()
{
   //… loading data into my collections
   MyFilterView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FirstFilter);
   MyFilterView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(ItemsFilter);
}
```

Last thing to do, to make this work, is install the method that will handle the filter event in my viewModel:

```
private bool ItemsFilter(object o)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(CurrentFilter)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      if(CurrentFilter == „All Items“)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         DataItem d = new DataItem();

         return (d.Item == o.Item);
      }
   }
}
```

Essentially – that’s it for running ONE filter. 
How can I implement the other filters? 
What I tried so far:

- Assign another ICollectionView (does not work – the datagrid is always empty, even if the DefaultView is set to the same collection)
- Try to set the MyFilterView.Filter in seperate methods, each at a time. This „kinda“ works, as long as my list is not build on hierachical structures: the code turns up to be a mess, and for each new comboBox, I’d have to code a lot of nested if-statements, delegating them to the next checkpoint.
  Can someone explain me a simple way of achieving this? Code examples would be very welcome!
  Thank you very much!

[image: short example]

Answer (score 0):

It was important to see how `DataItem` is structured and how `ItemsList` and the other filter lists are populated.

Anyway, I'll suppose `DataItem` has 3 properties as `string Item`, `string Element` and `string value` and that `ItemsList` contains all the possible values for the `Item` field found in `DataList` plus `"All Items"`.

Inside `ItemsFilter` you can code whatever filter you want, so why don't implement in there the other two?

```cs
private bool ItemsFilter(object o)
{
    var dataItem = o as DataItem;

    // Item filter
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(CurrentFilter))
        if(CurrentFilter != "All Items")
            if (o.Item != CurrentFilter)
                return false;

    // Element filter
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(CurrentElement))
        if(CurrentElement != "All Elements")
            if (o.Element != CurrentElement)
                return false;

    // Value filter
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(CurrentValue))
        if(CurrentValue != "All Values")
            if (o.Value != CurrentValue)
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: Back then I came up with something similar, but it won't work properly. Here's why: the first statement will filter MyFilterView, the second will (based upon the filter results) filter it again, likewise the third. In other words: I might loose valid data entries. All I could find out so far is that for multiple filters to work I would have to instantiate a CollectionViewSource instance rather than using the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView() static method. Instantiating a CVS allows  multiple filters by providing a filter event. But how to?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you give an example where this setup might lose data?

Comment: Let's say, I was filtering for a value B, but there was no value B. Now MyFilterView would be empty, which would be reflected perfectly fine in the datagrid, but if change the filter to items B, the selection would still be empty, although there is an Item B. I think the problem is GetDefaultView(), but whenever I instantiate CVS, I can set .Filter += any method I like. But that leads me full circle back to the start, where I don't know how to proceed. Thank you anyway, Federico!

Comment: I think you can set .Filter+=method multiple times since it's an event. I still think there's something wrong in the conclusion of your example. It's correct that there are no row shown if no row have a value B, even if the rows match any other filter. When you have multiple filters they always work in an 'and' mode, so that you have to match all to pass. If you don't want any more the value filter you can set it back to "all values". If you have precise rules on how this multiple filter should work than I can help you, otherwise it's difficult for me to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ferderico Rossi:  thanks for your help - it was a tip into the right direction. See my answer, and you'll see, it's actually a lot more complicated. Can't say I fully understand it, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, I’ve come up with a solution that also takes MVVM into account. It may not be the most elegant, but maybe this can be seen as a kickstart one can refactor, and improve.
First off: you need to instantiate CollectionViewSource rather than install ICollectionView. So, in your viewModel:

```
public CollectionViewSource _primaryView;
public CollectionViewSource PrimaryView
{
   get {return _primaryView; }
   set
   {
   _primaryView = value;
   PropertyChange(nameof(_primaryView);
   }
}
```

Also instantiate your collection of items you want to filter. In my case:

```
//This is the collection you want to filter. In my case it holds fields for  
//objects of type item, element and value.

public ObservableCollection<FilterObjects> DefaultFilter {get; set;} = new     
ObservableCollection<FilterObject>();
```

You’ll then need to set PrimaryView’s source to your collection (the one you want to filter). We set this in the viewModel’s constructor. So in my case:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
   //Here I fill my dummy data to my collection I want to filter
   // -- load dummy data --

   //Then set PrimaryView.Source to the collection you want to filter
   PrimaryView.Source = DefaultFilter;
}
```

Next, set up your filters. Therefore you need two ComboBoxes in your View. Like so:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbItemFilter" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"    
SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">                    
</ComboBox>
```

ItemsList is just another property in my viewModel, and is basically a list of item objects. CurrentItem is a property of type string which holds the currently selected item of the comboBox. Do not forget to raise PropertyChange here:

```
private string _currentItem;
public string CurrentItem
{
get { return _currentItem; }
set
{
   _currentItem = value;

   PropertyChange(nameof(_currentItem));
}
```

}

Proceed accordingly for any other comboBox you might use as a filter. So, in my case, I have two more comboBoxes, bound to a List of type Element, and a List of type Value. Likewise, each comboBox‘ selected item is bound to a propert in my viewModel (CurrentElement, CurrentValue).
See that your dataContext for your view is set to your viewModel. I like to do this in XAML, so here it is:

```
<Window.DataContext>
<viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

ViewModels is a namespace that needs to be imported into the statements of my view. It’s pretty straight forward, but if you are unfamiliar with it: put all your viewModels in a folder in your solution called ‚ViewModels‘. Now you need to reference this folder in your XAML, like so:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_Templating.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
…
xmlns:viewModels ="clr-namespace:[nameOfYourProjectWithoutRectangularBrackets].    
[FoldernameWhereYourViewModels resideWithoutRectangularBrackets]"
```

Last thing you’ll have to do here, is show your datagrid where it’s getting it’s data from. So you’ll need to set up the itemsSource as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgMainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryView.View}"  
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"> </DataGrid>
```

Make sure, it’s the CollectionViewSource’s view property you are binding to – otherwise it just won’t work!

From this point onward, all you have to do, is set up the filter logic. Boy, this gave me nightmares, but it works!. So, once more, go to your viewModel, and change this in your CurrentItem (CurrentElement / CurrentValue) property:

```
private string _currentItem;
public string CurrentItem
{
   get { return _currentItem; }
   set
       {
         _currentItem = value;

         if (CurrentValue == „Show all Items“)
       {
         ApplyElementFilter();
         ApplyValueFilter();
       }
         else
       {
         ApplyItemFilter();
       }       

         PropertyChange(nameof(_currentItem));
     }
}
```

This part is very tricky, and I am still not quiet sure, what is happening here – I got the desired result more or less by happy accident… Just make sure that if you have a filter criteria like „Select all persons“ or „Show all categories“ (kinda a default setting) that it’ll start all the other filters you have  look at the next paragraph, I’m sure the code is quiet selfexplanatory about this.
ApplyElementFilter() and ApplyValueFilter (or any other Filter you like) have to be implemented within your viewModel:

```
private void ApplyItemFilter()
{
   PrimaryView.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(FilterByItems);
   PrimaryView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByItems);           
}

private void ApplyElementFilter()
{
   PrimaryView.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(FilterByElement);
   PrimaryView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByElement);            
}

private void ApplyValueFilter()
{
   PrimaryView.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(FilterByValue);
   PrimaryView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByValue);            
}
```

You’re close to it, so bear with me. Last thing you gotta do is assign the methods you referenced in the FilterEventHandler. They are all the same, so for simplicities sake I only refer to one:

```
public void FilterByItems(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
```

{
        var src = e.Item as Item;

```
   if (src == null)
   {
      e.Accepted = false;
      else if (CurrentItem== "Show all Items")
      e.Accepted = true;
   }
   else if (string.Compare(CurrentItem, src.CurrentItem) != 0)
   {
      e.Accepted = false;           
   }
```

This is a whole lot to swallow at first, but as I said before: I am sure there are ways to get this functionality, and get away with it more elegant. Hope someone out there can make use of this.
Cheers